# Java: JUnit tests run in IntelliJ but not in Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, pom.xml

I've written some JUnit tests and, according to how our our boss decided, these tests sit on some laptop and being run manually when needed, by someone right-clicking (in IntelliJ) the test class and "run".

Now, someone finally listened to me and picked up the tests for running automatically, in the build system... However, this way we've found out that the tests don't even compile from command line!

On the same machine, which has only one JDK installed - Oracle JDK-8 (and I guess the JBR that comes with IntelliJ),  IntelliJ reports no problems when editing the code, nor when compiling and running the code successfully... But when I use IntelliJ's terminal: mvn test -Pmytests - it complains about some missing packages (and stops the build):

`[ERROR] /C:/.../soaptest/customhttp/HttpSoapConnection.java:[3,43] package com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj does not exist`

I want to know what is it that IntelliJ knows, that Maven doesn't? I try to keep the configuration as same as possible between Maven and IntelliJ. So, that we don't have any craziness like this and things work even without the IDE... Actually, my project is super simple... Pretty sure everything in IntelliJ is just the defaults.

I am sorry I don't know exactly what more to share with you, I have no idea what could be the difference. If someone suggests things to check, I will update! :)

- Oh, one idea that I have: I looked into the resulting "run configuration" that IntelliJ creates when rightclick-run-ing the class and I see it does `-cp mymodule` - is that something I need to configure in the pom.xml file?

Update: Since the classes I am having trouble to compile are linked to each other, I've been unable to show just "one" class in my reproducible example. Instead, I've hugely cut down the project and uploaded here: https://github.com/DraxDomax/intellijmaven

To reproduce (requires JDK8): 
1] Open in IntelliJ and right-click on the `src/test/java/com/nominet/qa/proto/SoapProtoTest.java` and then "run" 
= This will run a test that will fail - but notice that the method gets executed because it compiled...

2] Delete the target folder 
3] In the command line (I used the IDEA Terminal), type: mvn test -Psurefiredemo 
= Notice now the test doesn't even get run and you get compilation errors!

Comment: If possible try to create a [mre]. Favourable would be if we could see the `pom.xml`, some source file *and* test file, so that we could try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Currently it is very hard to help you because all we can do is guess work. IDEs are complicated, and build systems like maven also come with their quirks

Comment: I was afraid you might say that :) I'll start cutting out my project and will update soon. Thanks

Comment: @Lino Done. I couldn't do it very small, as the files that don't compile are linked to each other and it's a bit of a mess to pick one and plug it up so that it "should" compile.

Comment: The most likely reason for that behavior is that someone added a *dependency* to the IntelliJ-configuration (and checked that into the SCM) but not to the POMs `<dependencies>` section.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I don't see how :( I've got someone on my team to reproduce this and they only got the src folder and the pom.xml... Their IntelliJ was just installed and wouldn't have any set up on it.

Answer (score 2):

I execute unit tests from both IntelliJ and the command line using **mvn test**.

My IntelliJ project:

[image]

My Java project has this class:

```
package com.example;

public class Test1 {

    public String foo() {

        return "1";
    }

    public String foo2() {

        return "2";
    }

    public String foo3() {

        return "3";
    }
}
```

My Test class is this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import com.example.*;

import java.io.*;

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)

public class TestClass {


    public static Test1 testOb;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws IOException {


        testOb = new Test1();
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void whenInitializingAWSService_thenNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(testOb);
        System.out.println("Running SNS Test 1");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void callFoo() {

        testOb.foo();
        System.out.println("Test 2 passed");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(3)
    public void callFoo2() {

        testOb.foo2();
        System.out.println("Test 3 passed");
    }

    @Test
    @Order(4)
    public void callFoo3() {

        testOb.foo3();
        System.out.println("Test 4 passed");
    }
}
```

My POM is this. Make sure you have this plug-in too:

[Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My test was successful from IntelliJ:

[image]

My tests were successful from the command line using mvn test.

[image]

**UPDATE....**

I downloaded your project from Github. It did not work from the command line. I updated your POM to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>qatoolbox</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>qatoolbox</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I changed the logic in the test class as the point of this was not to actually test your code but to ensure the tests are executed from the command line. After I updated the POM - the tests were successfully executed via the command line.
[image]

Comment: I tried moving the source-target config into the plug in (if it's a different version being caught, somehow) - same result. I didn't adopt your AWS SDK... I got the entire JUnit-Jupiter dep (which includes all your JUnit deps)... Still same result :( Gave you a + for trying to help, though :) Was wondering if you could try and reproduce, using provided cut-down project?

Comment: Of course - I will try remove the AWS dependencies and run it.

Comment: I am talking about my project :) (it has no AWS deps)

Comment: This new project I posted above has no AWS dependencies and shows how to setup POM dependencies to successfully run a JUNIT test from the command line. It works as shown in my screenshots.

Comment: Your POM file was the problem.

Comment: See the updated part of this thread. After i modified your POM - it works from the command line.

Comment: Thanks. I've copy pasted the pom you provided right instead of mine - still getting "package com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj does not exist"... When you said my project did not work - was that the problem (saaj missing) or something else?

Comment: also, if you've run the test using the IDE, the project gets built properly and then it works from CMD too... (Which makes it look like it got fixed)